# Django Python - Add table values inside common header

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

Maybe trying to do something not possible but basically, I created a file header.html that I include all other my html pages e.g. {%  include "project/header.html" %}
This works fine the challenge is that on header.html I want to put a dropdown menu with values coming from a model. it works fine if I invoke directly header.html but not when inside other page.

**header.html**

```
...
<ul>
{% for club in clubs.all %}
<li> <a href="#">{{ club.name }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
...
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

from .models import Club
def index(request):
    clubs = Club.objects
    return render(request, 'project/index.html',{'clubs':clubs})
```

Is this even possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a [*context processor* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors) for this. This is a method that is each time added to the request.

In an app (any app that you use) you can define a context processor:

```
# app/context_processors.py

def all_clubs(request):
    from app.models import Club
    return {
        'clubs': Club.objects.all()
    }
```

then you register this context processor in the `settings.py` file, such that it will be added to the context in each `render(…)` call:

```
# settings.py

# …

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        # …
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                # …
                'app.context_processors.all_clubs'
            ]
        }
        # …
    }
]
```

Now you do no longer need to pass `clubs` in each render call. It will automatically be added. Since `QuerySet`s are lazy, it will not hit the database if your template does not use `clubs`.

Comment: Thank you very much Willem. Problem sorted. I must keep reading through Python documentation for sure!!